# Necesito ayuda con el reflexivo en frases que tienen un pronombre de objeto indirecto en frente de ello

Tags: aspecto-gramatical

Cuando estaba mirando en la historia de instagram de amigo mio, encontré un frase que dijó "Solo imagina que hoy 14 de Febrero tu Crush se te declare 'sería lindo no?'" lo que me confunde es "se le declare" porque pensé que es incorrecto tener un se antes de 'le' o un objeto indirecto pero me dí cuenta que es solo porque es un verbo reflexivo. A veces yo veo estos frases similares. El problema es como se traduce esto en ingles y como se usa tambien? Hay una explicacion?

Gracias! :)

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Comprendes el significado de la frase que has puesto? Parece que estás preguntando cómo se traduce "se le" al inglés en general, pero eso es difícil de decir porque el significado de "se" varía mucho según el verbo al que acompañe. ¿Podrías aclarar si es eso lo que estás preguntando?

Comment: Si la traducción de eso pero también estoy preguntando porque hay “se” antes de “le”? En ejemplos lo cual uno de ellos ya dije de arriba

Answer (score 2):

El verbo *declararse*, como ya sabes, es pronominal o reflexivo. La forma básica del verbo, *declarar*, es muy parecida al "to declare" del inglés, pero la forma reflexiva no se puede traducir literalmente.

En inglés, "to declare oneself" requiere algo más (por ejemplo, "I declare myself in love with you"). En español, en cambio, *declararse* significa ya "to declare oneself in love with someone", "to declare one's love for someone". No necesita añadir nada más sobre qué cosa se declaró.

Para expresar **a quién** declaró su amor la persona, hay que añadir un pronombre, por ejemplo: *Se **te** declaró* (donde *te* = "a ti").

El pronombre reflexivo es *se* si la persona es la tercera (del singular o plural: "él, ellos, ella, ellas"). Si es otra, cambiará según corresponda. Por ejemplo: *Me le declaré* ("I declared myself in love with him/her"). For some reason it's wrong to say *Me te declaré* ("I declared myself in love with you"), though...

Comment: Se puede decir **Te me declaré** en ese caso, "I declared myself in love with you".